# facebook messenger api, templates doesn't works

Tags: json, facebook, api, curl, bots

When i send this json data with PHP curl to Facebook Messenger Bot api, it works fine.

$jsonData = '{
         "recipient":{
         "id":"'.$sender.'"
         }, 
          "message":{
             "text":"'.$obj.'"
          }
        }';

but, when I'm using templates from FB page. Templates doesn't works

```
$jsonData = '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"'.$sender.'"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic",
        "elements":[
           {
            "title":"Hello",
            "image_url":"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png",
            "subtitle":"Title",
            "default_action": {
              "type": "web_url",
              "url": "https://google.com",
              "messenger_extensions": true,
              "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
              "fallback_url": "https://google.com/"
            },
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"web_url",
                "url":"https://google.com",
                "title":"View Website"
              },{
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Start Chatting",
                "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
              }              
            ]      
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}';
```

I'm trying to encode to Json, replace a buttons, nothing happens. Facebook templates doesn't works after messenger update, or i need to use new parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1: `google.com` is in your whitelist.
2: its HTTPS but not HTTP

Or you will get error like this

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The URL provided is not whitelisted for messenger extensions","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018062,"fbtrace_id":"GNd1AXlQsjz"}}
```

And I guess if you remove `default_aciton` it will work :)